# 2 farms (portal and BI) different authentication

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, architecture

I am new to this company and they have 2 farms for SharePoint 2010 (regular portal and Business Intel). The portal authentication is windows ntlm and BI farm is setup with kerberos.

There are no documentations as why they have the BI farm setup with Kerberos.

The farm is small 15 small sites and total 12 GB data.

I am evaluating both farms and thinking of combining portal and bi into one farm once we go to SP 2013. - What's you all thought on this?

(bi farm is 2 apps, 2 wfe, 2 report servers, 2 sql servers). They are not using anywhere close to this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Main reason i am thinking why they have 2 separate farms as we had same thing for SharePoint 2010. BI component requires Enterprise licensing while mostly portal farm are on standard edition of SharePoint. Enterprise edition cost alot and it is really headache in SharePoint 2010 to manage all the user cal for EE.

You can check the SharePoint version on both farm if that is the case.

Yes, you can combine both farms into one but its depend upon the company's requirement. things you have to check before making any decision.

- SharePoint edition on both farm ( enterprise or Standard)
- Usage of Both farm ( BI required more resources)
- User base on both farms.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you they are probably utilizing Kerberos for the per-user identity for PerformancePoint, at least that was my initial thought. It allows SharePoint to stop users from the database level instead from only the application level. This allows users to see reports, but access to certain objects in SSAS. I'd check to see if they are using Kerberos for that reason, however I would pack the portal farm into the BI farm configuration if you are, so you don't need to reset any of the SPNs used for Kerberos. In other words, bring the content dbs over from portal and mount them onto the bi portal farm, but you'll need to make sure the portal farm build version is less than or equal to the BI farm, otherwise it will stop you from mounting the content DBs.